# Removing &nbsp; single or multiple from the url or link in php

Tags: php, html

Removing `&nbsp;` single or multiple from the url or link like:

```
www.makeuseof.com/tag/7-tips-tricks-google-drive/&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Comment: please read this first: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/question

Comment: There is no `&nbsp;` on this link `http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/7-tips-tricks-google-drive/` except in the source code

Comment: because its remove by stackoverflow.. if there is at the end of url how can i remove

Answer (score 2):

This will remove all the `&nbsp;` elements within the `$link` string:

```
$link = str_replace('&nbsp;','',$link);
```